# Gulp: 'since' and 'gulp-remember' do not pass the renamed files

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

When I tried `gulp.srs({since: gulp.lastRun('taskName')})` and `gulp-remember` I noticed that renaming file is not considering as changing file. So, when I rename the file, both `gulp.srs({since: gulp.lastRun('taskName')})` and `gulp-remember` filters do not pass the rename file. What should I do?

```
gulp.task('testTask', () => {
    gulp.src(globFilesSelection,
     {since: gulp.lastRun('testTask') }) // filtering on the file selection step from second gulp run
        .pipe(plugins.newer(outputPath)) // filtering already selected files from first gulp run
        // and so on, no important code from here
})
```

Dumped value of `globFilesSelection`:

```
[ 'C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\testProject\\development\\source\\common\\images\\**\\*',
  'C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\testProject\\development\\source\\open\\images\\**\\*',
  'C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\testProject\\development\\source\\admin\\images\\**\\*',
  'C:\\OpenServer\\domains\\testProject\\development\\source\\development\\images\\**\\*' ]
```

Comment: @Mark I added the relevant code. Let me repeat that `since` and `gulp-newer` working properly: OS don't update the file changing date after renaming it, so `since` and `gulp.newer` do noting.

Comment: Sometimes the way you have your gulp.src files makes a difference here: show your "globFilesSelection" variable.

Comment: @Mark, It has been initialized in my own class, but I'll show you the dumped value.